What is the correct syntax formula when attempting to make a text field mandatory?
I'm attempting to setup List Validation to enforce a "Multiple lines of Text" (High Prioritization Selected - Explain Why) Column be required if the Prioritization within Value Stream Column is set to "High". If the Prioritization within Value Stream Column is set to "Medium" or Low" the High Prioritization Selected - Explain Why is not required.
Appreciate the assistance!

Is this a plain text or rich text "multiple lines or text" field?

I did a test and selected the Prioritization within Value Stream Column as the column of Choice. In list settings, click Validation settings and enter the following formula:
=IF([Prioritization within Value Stream]="High",IF(ISBLANK([High Prioritization Selected - Explain Why]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)

It works fine in my environment.

